# Reversing a linked list using recursive method

Tags: java, recursion, methods

I am having trouble resolving this code problem. I need to reverse a linked list using recursive method in Java. I can't seem to figure it out and I have tried to the extent of my knowlege. I would really appreciate some help.

```
// Java program for reversing the linked list

class MyLinkedList {

    static Node head;

    static class Node {

        int data;
        Node next;

        Node(int d) {
            data = d;
            next = null;
        }
    }

    /* Function to reverse the linked list */
    Node reverse(Node node) {


          add content      


        node = prev;
        return node;
    }

    // prints content of double linked list
    void printList(Node node) {
        while (node != null) {
            System.out.print(node.data + " ");
            node = node.next;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyLinkedList list = new MyLinkedList();
        add content    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this recursively? Is the list a doubly-linked list? Is this homework?!

Comment: What have you tried yet exactly? This problem sounds like homework or a lab. There are plenty of resources on Google for this specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "add content" there should be:

1. Remember the Node that your ***next*** Node references to.
2. Assign the field of the ***next*** Node the value of your ***current*** Node.
3. Make the ***next*** Node the ***current*** one.
4. Make the Node from step 1 the ***next*** one.
5. GOTO 1

(A) -> (B) where A is the ***current*** Node and B is the ***next*** Node.

Answer (score 0):

Before you try to solve this using recursion try to imagine this first.

Given (1)->(2)->(3)->

Initialize 3 variables prev = null; cur = 1; next = 2;

Now to reverse this, start from the current node, it must point to the previous but by doing so we lose the link between 1 and 2. To keep the link set next = 2. Now the current 1 can now point to the previous value i.e. cur.next = prev.

So now we have <-(1) (2)->(3)->

Then to go to the next iteration you just need to update prev = cur and cur = next.

By doing this repeatedly until you reach a null the linked list updates this way.

<-(1)<-(2) (3)->

<-(1)<-(2)<-(3)

So this can be done with a while loop like this

```
Node prev = null;
Node cur = node;
Node next;
while (cur != null) {
    next = cur.next;
    cur.next = prev;
    prev = cur;
    cur = next;
}

return prev;
```

Now to do this using recursion you just need to have 3 parameters, i.e. the prev, cur, and next. Define your base case (what should the function do when it reaches null). Then do the 4 lines of code inside the while loop then call the recursive function.